# Scala Transactions and data consistency

Tags: scala, transactions, h2, slick

I'm wondering what can i do to be sure that my code is thread safe while "renting" a book.

```
  def rentBook(intNum: Int): Future[Unit] = Future[Unit] {
    val book = Await.result(bookRep.getById(intNum), 5 seconds).get
    if(book.available) {
      val updatedBook = Book(intNum, book.title, book.authID, available = false)
      bookRep.updateById(intNum, updatedBook)
    }
  }
```

Basically here i'm obtaining book which I want to rent, check if it's available and then update it to make it unavailble. But here we have obvious error, which will allow two users rent same book in certain condition (they search for book, obtain book at the same time, and for both of them book is available). This is service class. How can i make this transaction atomic using Slick Scala? I'm connecting to H2 Database.

I tried with synchronized block, but i'm wondering if there is better way?

Comment: Let Slick handle it: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/dbio.html#transactions-and-pinned-sessions

Comment: Also, why do you wait for the first future to complete? This blocks the thread. You should compose the futures using `flatMap`.

Comment: @marstran Thanks, i will, but for the first opinion, i can't to this in service class, it works on obtained data from database, under the hood in bookRep( BookRepositoryImpl ) i'm using slick for obtaining data, that is why i can't connect those in transaction

Comment: You could also return `DBIO` instead of `Future`, compose 2 `DBIO`s, make a transaction out of them, and that interpret with database. (Assuming that you are using Slick 3.)

Comment: In this case you are updating only one field and don't returning book object from this method. I can recommend to write query that update book availability by book id. Slick will return number of updated rows. And depend on returned value you can throw exception or return boolean result.